# How to report Copyright infringement on Wikipedia?

Tags: wikipedia, copyright

I have found a few images on the English wikipedia that are under copyright. I'm not the owner of the copyright. The real owners of the copyright are too technologically illiterate to do anything about this.

How and where can one report Copyright infringement on Wikipedia?

Comment: Have you even tried using Google before asking the question here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are the holder of the Copyright (as it sounds like you are) Wikipedia has a [Request for immediate removal of copyright violation](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia%3aRequest_for_immediate_removal_of_copyright_violation&redirect=no) process. The most straightforward method seems to be:

> If you're worried that we're using your copyrighted works improperly,
>   you can email us at **`info-en-c@wikimedia.org`** . Please provide the
>   address or title of the page, and evidence to show that you are the
>   legitimate copyright holder.

Other "formal" methods are also included in their detailed documentation on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright violation is one of the [criteria for "Speedy Deletion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCSD#F9).

Simply edit the file page(s) violating copyright and put at the top of the page.

```
 {{db-filecopyvio}}
```

There is *lots and lots* of information at [Wikipedia: Copyright violation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aCopyright_violations).

Comment: He's asking about images, not articles.

Comment: @Asa: I've changed my answer to be about reporting files.